# KeyboardAvoidingView is not supporting in IOS devices

Tags: react-native

I want to get the textInputs without covering by Keyboard.

I have tried with keyboardAvoidingView but it is only supports in Android.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView>
    <SafeAreaView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
       <View style={styles.middleView}>
          <Text>Login</Text>
          <TextInput
             placeholder="example@google.com"
             placeholderTextColor="#a4b0be"
             returnKeyType="go"
             keyboardType="email-address"
             autoCapitalize="none"
             autoCorrect={false}
             autoFocus={true}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity>
             <Text style=Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

How I can solve this. Is there any other library to do this?

Comment: According to the official [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview) it is supported by both iOS and Android. What is your problem? Try to set a `keyboardVerticalOffset` prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install React Native Keyboard Spacer,

```
npm install --save react-native-keyboard-spacer
```

You can use this for iOS Application. KeyboardAoidingView is working perfectly in Android. So apply this library only for iOS platform.

```
import KeyboardSpacer from 'react-native-keyboard-spacer';

{Platform.OS === 'android' && 
     <KeyboardAvoidingView>
          <SafeAreaView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
              <View style={styles.middleView}>
                   <Text>Login</Text>
                   <TextInput
                       placeholder="example@google.com"
                       placeholderTextColor="#a4b0be"
                       returnKeyType="go"
                       keyboardType="email-address"
                       autoCapitalize="none"
                       autoCorrect={false}
                       autoFocus={true}
                   />
                   <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style=Login</Text>
                   </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
         </SafeAreaView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
}
{Platform.OS === 'iOS' && 
     <SafeAreaView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
         <View style={styles.middleView}>
             <Text>Login</Text>
             <TextInput
                  placeholder="example@google.com"
                  placeholderTextColor="#a4b0be"
                  returnKeyType="go"
                  keyboardType="email-address"
                  autoCapitalize="none"
                  autoCorrect={false}
                  autoFocus={true}
             />
             <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text style=Login</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
         <KeyboardSpacer/>
     </SafeAreaView>         
}
```

Answer (score 4):

KeyboardAvoidingView behaves differently on iOS and Android. On iOS is it recommended to add the behavior props, and I usually use 'padding' which works fine in most cases:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : undefined}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve the keyboard issue in iPhone and Android I recommend you to use the awesome package

https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view